# Sending MongoDB aggregation with date range from PHP

Tags: php, mongodb, aggregation

I am trying to send a mongodb aggregation from my Laravel app, that would aggregate only the data in a setup date range. The app has a  [date range picker](http://www.daterangepicker.com/), that returns fromDate and toDate which I’m converting into ISODate format and than passing the variables into the aggregation pipeline as shown below:

```
private function getMongoData($fromDate = null, $toDate = null){

   $collection = (new Client())->database->collection;

   $fromDate = "ISODate('".$fromDate."')";
   $toDate = "ISODate('".$toDate."')";


   $pipeline = [
       [
           '$match' => [
               'event_date' => ['$gt' => $fromDate, '$lt' => $toDate],
           ],
       ],
   ];

   $result = $collection->aggregate($pipeline)->toArray();
```

Above is just the match stage of the aggregation as without it the rest of the aggregation seems to be working fine. With this date range its returning an empty array

This is what my app is currently sending to mongo:

```
event_date: {$gt: "ISODate('2017-01-10T00:00:00+01:00')", $lt: "ISODate('2018-01-10T23:59:59+01:00')"}
```

Im pretty new to php and mongo and this struggle is giving me some serious headaches, so I would appreciate any advice on this

Comment: ISODate is a shell type not a php type.Use php mongo UTCdatetime Something like `$fromDate = new \MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime(strtotime('2018-01-10T00:00:00-05:00') * 1000);`

Comment: Thanks @Veeram! this made it: `$fromDate = new UTCDateTime(strtotime($fromDate) * 1000);`